# Understanding how Router.go() works in Meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm just learning Meteor now from the great Discover Meteor book and I'm struggling to understand something about how Router.go() functions which I thought might be something that other beginners could use an answer to.

**Context:** The code below does what it's supposed to - it picks up the url and title values from the postSubmit form (code not included for the form) and uses that to create a new post. Then it uses `Router.go()` to take the user to the `postPage` template at a *posts/:_id* url, displaying the information for the newly created post. This code all works.

**My question is:** I would expect that when you call `Router.go()`, as well as passing in the 'postPage' template, what you would need to pass in as the second parameter is the post **id** element in the form `{_id: post._id}` (which also works, I've tried it) as that is what the route requires. So why am I passing in the `post` var (which includes the url and title) rather than the ID?

Here's my code:

```
//post_submit.js
Template.postSubmit.events({ 'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var post = {
    url: $(e.target).find('[name=url]').val(),
    title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val()
    };

    post._id = Posts.insert(post);
    //THE 'post' PARAMETER HERE INSTEAD OF '{_id: post._id}' IS WHAT I'M QUESTIONING
    Router.go('postPage', post);
    }
});
```

And the code for the router:

```
//Route for the postPage template
Router.route('/posts/:_id',
  {name: 'postPage',
  data: function(){ return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question - I also found this confusing when I first saw it. Here's a sketch of what's going on:

1. The router parses `/posts/:_id` and figures out that it should be passed a context object which contains an `_id` field.
2. You call `Router.go` with a context object that contains an `_id` field.
3. The router takes your context object and copies the value of `_id` into `this.params`.

Because the router understands which fields are required (and ignores the rest), it doesn't actually matter if you pass in `{_id: 'abc123'}` or `{_id: 'abc123', title: 'hello', author: 'bob'}.` The fact that the latter works is simply a convenience so you don't have to extract the `_id` into a separate object.

Comment: Thanks David, Meteor is just so much more 'intelligent' than most frameworks, sometimes I can't quite believe it!